# How do I synchronize the address book in my app using MAPI?

Tags: c++, mapi

The system I'm working on contains an address book. I am looking for sample code that will synchronize addresses with the current users address book through MAPI. I need two-way sync.

If you know of any open-source library with easy to use functions for this, I'd be glad to hear about it. If you know of a library that is not open-source, well, that is fine too. The best would be a library which license will allow me to use it in our own solution.

And if you, god forbid, know of a library that will make it *easy* for me to publish my address book in a MAPI provider - well, then I'm dying to hear about it!

Using an external address book and ditching our own is not an option that would serve our customers.

A good, working code sample using vanilla MAPI is of course also acceptable. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Zarafa just [released their 100% MAPI compatible groupware suite as GPL](http://www.zarafa.com/?q=en/content/products).  Maybe that's useful for you?

EDIT: The link is slashdotted.  [More info here.](http://linux.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=08/09/19/2023252)

Comment: This is indeed very interesting. But I must refrain from looking at GPL code in this case, unfortunately.